# inheriting prototypes. why does it use create()?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

in this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance#setting_teachers_prototype_and_constructor_reference...

to inherit prototypes, why does it use
`Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);`
and not simply using

```
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
```

Comment: For what it's worth this looks like ES5 material. In ES6 this is `class Teacher extends Person` with [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: oh, so this kind of programming is outdated ? @tadman

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much defunct now that ES6 is supported by virtually anything you'll see in the wild. The new class-based approach fixes a *lot* of the things that made JavaScript classes unnecessarily ugly.

Comment: @tadman It's still important to understand how prototypes and the inheritance chain of a class work, and how the `Object.create` primitive is a basic building block.

Comment: @Bergi Debatable. It really depends on what your objectives are.

Comment: Without `Object.create`, if the property of the `prototype` was an Object, that Object would be referenced by both instances, so setting that Object property in one `new` instance would appear to affect other `new` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifics here are to do with how the ES5 and prior versions of inheritance work. The `prototype` property defines functions that class members can use.

If you were to directly assign then any functions added to `Teacher` would also back-propagate to `Person`, as in:

```js
Teacher.prototype = Person.prototype;
Teacher.prototype.name = function(...) { }
```

Where that `name()` function now impacts `Person` as well. `Object.create()` effects a cloning operation meaning the two prototypes are now independent.

The way this plays out in ES6 is a lot different, and arguably a lot cleaner:

```js
class Teacher extends Person {
  name() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This still generates the same `Teacher.prototype` at the end of the day, the internals are effectively the same, but the composition of classes is vastly simplified.